# How to open phone dialer in blackberry10 in cordova javascript?

Tags: javascript, cordova, blackberry-10

I used

```
 window.open('tel:18007774673', '_system');
```

For android and iPhone it's working.
But for blackberry10, it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using,

```
 window.location.href='tel:xxxxxxxxxxx';// java script
```

we can open dialer in blackberry10